# Python: Get XML data and put in multi value dictionary

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have some data in XML that I need to be stored in a dictionary.
The **XML file** is as follows:

```
<market>
   <grocery>
      <items>
         <item>
            <name>Apple</name>
            <seller>AppleSeller</seller>
            <quantity>30</quantity>
            <price>10</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>Orange</name>
            <seller>OrangeGuy</seller>
            <quantity>25</quantity>
            <price>20</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>Banana</name>
            <seller>BananaMan</seller>
            <quantity>35</quantity>
            <price>5</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>Apple</name>
            <seller>AppleSeller</seller>
            <quantity>67</quantity>
            <price>20</price>
         </item>
      </items>
   </grocery>

   <cleaning>
      <items>
         <item>
            <name>Disinfectant</name>
            <seller>MrClean</seller>
            <quantity>24</quantity>
            <price>50</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <name>Mop</name>
            <seller>MopIndustries</seller>
            <quantity>5</quantity>
            <price>30</price>
         </item>
      </items>
   </cleaning>

</market>
```

So I need to get the data and sort it according to the first child (grocery, cleaning, etc) in a **Python3** script which needs to use **XML ElementTree**.

The final dictionary (or something else) should store the data by keeping unique names (Apple, Orange, Banana, etc) something like this:

```
sorted_dictionary = {
"grocery": ["Apple", "AppleSeller", "30", "10"],
"grocery": ["Orange", "OrangeGuy", "25", "20"],
"grocery": ["Banana", "BananaMan", "35", "5"],
"cleaning": ... (same as how grocery does it)
"cleaning": ...
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). do not expect people here to write code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create same key for all elements in dictionary.
check below code it will create list of all groceries.

You can do same for other elements

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)
names = [i.text for i in root.findall('grocery/items/item/name')]
seller = [i.text for i in root.findall('grocery/items/item/seller')]
quantity = [i.text for i in root.findall('grocery/items/item/quantity')]
price = [i.text for i in root.findall('grocery/items/item/price')]
ls = [list(i) for i in zip(names,seller,quantity,price)]
print(ls)
d = {"grocery": ls}
print(d)
```